# Is there a proof for this limit cycle equilibrium

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, limit-cycles

Consider a system of differential equations where both are both continuous partial derivatives. Let's call them $F$ and $G$. Is there a proof suggesting that if there exists a solution that is a limit cycle of the system (call it $l(t)$), the system must then have an equilibrium solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a theorem that a closed trajectory always encloses at least one equilibrium point. See e.g. [Boyce and diPrima](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Elementary+Differential+Equations+and+Boundary+Value+Problems%2C+10th+Edition-p-9780470458310), theorem 9.7.1.

Comment: I cannot access this document. Is there a note where I can see the theorem?

Comment: Try [this](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Ca9ysS04kgoC&pg=PA520&lpg=PA520#v=onepage&q&f=false) where it's theorem 7.5.1.